# Keyboard characters in script record

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I am using `script` to record a terminal session. However, inside my recorded text file, the text input and output is interlaced with strange characters that  look like:

```
^M^[[K^[[A^[[C^ $vim session ^M
^[[?1049h^[[?1h^[=^[[1;21r^[[?12;25h^[[?12l^[[?25h^[[27m^[[m^[[H^[[2J^[[?25l^[[21;1H"session"
[noeol] 3L, 855C^
```

I think these correspond to return keys and other keyboard commands. Is there a way to not record these during a `script` session?

Comment: No, there's no way not to record them. You can use `col -b filename` to display the script with them filtered out.

Comment: This isn't a computer programming question, it's about using the computer. It belongs on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Those aren't keyboard commands, they're the escape sequences used to move the cursor around the screen.

Comment: Ok I see. I tried doing ``cat session |col -b `` but the output still contains these escape sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example given,

```
^M^[[K^[[A^[[C^ $vim session ^M
^[[?1049h^[[?1h^[=^[[1;21r^[[?12;25h^[[?12l^[[?25h^[[27m^[[m^[[H^[[2J^[[?25l^[[21;1H"session"
[noeol] 3L, 855C^
```

you have a mixture of cursor-movement and other escape-sequences.  The `^[` is the escape character, and `^M` is carriage return.  As noted, `script` records everything sent to the terminal, and full-screen programs such as `vim` will always use these escape sequences.  For instance, picking it apart

```
^[[K
```

clears the line,

```
^[[C
```

moves the cursor,

```
^[[?1049h
```

switches the terminal to the alternate screen,

```
^[[1;21r
```

sets scrolling margins

```
^[[?12;25h
```

sets *modes* (12 for blinking cursor, 25 to ensure the cursor is visible).  Oddly, vim next stops blinking the cursor, resets video attributes with

```
^[[27m
^[[m
^[[H
```

before moving the cursor to the upper left

```
^[[J
```

and clearing the screen, and *then* hides the cursor again before

```
^[[21;1H"session"
[noeol] 3L, 855C
```

jumping to the lower left of the screen and printing a message (for reference, *[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)*).  So there is a lot going on, and it is not simply printing the screen left-to-right and top-to-bottom.

Since you are using `script`, it captures the output into a "typescript" file.  If you want to filter those into readable form, a pager such as `less` using its `-R` option works passably well—but it misses things.  The terminal emulator (with the same screensize) is the best way I know to filter the results, e.g, using a program which sends the characters to the terminal slowly.  If you want plain text, select/paste from a replay (using `^S` and `^Q` to stop/resume) might be a way to go.

Comment: Great, the cursor movement disappeared if I used iTerm and then the less -R removed the rest of the escape sequences. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A UNIX terminal has two modes, canonical and non-canonical (also known as 'cooked' and 'raw').

The `script` program works by inserting itself into the message queue stack between the terminal driver and the shell (that's simplified).

The shell thinks it is talking to a terminal when it is talking with `script`.  So what you see is what the shell sees, the raw terminal characters.

Try `strings typescript`